# Not Collection Type For GenericEntity

Tags: java, jersey, jsonp

I use GenericEntity: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html for my JSONP responses. However when I use it I have to return a Collection. How can I return simple String at my case?

Answer (score 0):

Which jax-rs implementation are you using?

I have personally NOT ever used GenericEntity for anything but lists of things. If you want to return a jsonp response from a single Object then try using com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONWithPadding if you're in jersey 1.x.

```
@GET
@Path("/jsonp")
public JSONWithPadding getJSONP(@QueryParam("callback") String callback) {

    return new JSONWithPadding(objectToReturn, callback);

}
```

Comment: When I use text/plain is it possible to hit the cross side issue?

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS the accepted content type headers are application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain with GET, HEAD, or POST. Preflighted requests are required for other content types.

Comment: You mean plain text will not have problem? On the other hand what if I am using a newer jersey version?